# is it possible to combine the contains() function in Xpath?

Tags: html, xpath

I want to get a text that contains the word "com" but **not** to contain the word "blog" . Is it possible for these two conditions to be combined ?

example :

```
<html>
www.games.com
www.gamerblog.com
www.sports.com
</html>
```

result = [www.games.com , www.sports.com]

Comment: I have tried the logical And and & symbol but within a single function contains .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use logical NOT with logical AND with two separate `contains` calls:

```
contains(., "com") and not(contains(., "blog"))
```